# dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server

Tags: 16.04, mysql

After I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 I get the error below when trying to install new software

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
```

Please anyone help.

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl status mysql.service`? If it is that the start failed, then what was reported in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`?

Comment: I run that code i get **Failed to start MySQL Community Server** this error. Error log is empty

Comment: Before you can figure out what's going on here, you need to make your error log work. By default this is set in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` - the line that starts `log_error`. If you have modified your configuration locally, you will need to update it. If `/etc/mysql/my.cnf.migrated` exists, read the instructions there.